# Why can't I see all comments on my own YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I own a video. In the video manager, it shows the following:

[image: screen shot from video manager, redacted]

Also, when I view the video, I see this:

[image: screen shot from video page]

So what the hell is that? How many comments are there? Why can't I see all of them? I **replied** to both of the displayed existing comments, but **I can't see my replies** either.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me just say that this has not happened to me, and therefore I only know from troubleshooting other issues with people, but this is *the* most common answer.

**What you're going to need to do,** is access your YouTube account by **signing in,** of course.

**Next**, you will want to go to "[account privacy](https://www.youtube.com/account_privacy)". This will take you to your YouTube Privacy settings. (If not, log in first.)

**Then**, just look over your selected options. The issue may be apparent just by reviewing your settings, but if you can't figure it out still, be sure to make sure, first and foremost, that the box labelled *Make Comments Private* (or something of an equivalent meaning) is **not** checked.

*For future reference, please make sure to check all of your settings regardless of what you may think they are set to. There is an **extremely** high chance that it is something as simple as one or two check boxes!*

Answer (score 0):

YouTube moves some comments to other categories you don't see right away:  "Held for review", and "Likely spam".  When you're logged in, in a browser, you can see those at the URL [YouTube.com/comments](http://YouTube.com/comments).

[image: held for review and likely spam]

That might explain the discrepancy between the "6" and the "8" in your image - 2 of the comments might have been filed in one of those other categories.

Also, YouTube isn't so great when it comes to counting comments. For example, my screenshot shows "Likely spam" = 20. But when I go to that tab, it shows that there are *no* comments, even though I've selected "All videos" in the drop down on the right of the screen.

[image]

I think this might be due to how YouTube handles spam (which might be part of the situation you're experiencing). Here's my theory:  Some user posts the same self-serving comment on 100 videos. YouTube moves it to the "Likely spam" category for everybody. 50 people actually mark it as spam, which causes YouTube to delete it from the *other* 50 videos ... but it was still counted as a comment on those videos, even though the comment has been automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your comments are labeled as spam under comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the setting of your video where the tags are and change the "sort" to "newest" instead of top.